# LCA: why item response probabilities change when I change the order of items listed in the ITEM statement?

Tags: sas

I am new to Latent Class Analysis in SAS and probably this would be a silly question to ask, but I cannot understand why my item response probabilities change when I switch the order of the items included in the item statement? 
Everything else in my syntax stays the same, including a fixed seed number.This has been so frustrating...Thank you!

If running code 1, I w'd get item1 response probabilities such as: class 1 (0.9961), class 2 (0.1156), class 3 (0.9401), class 4 (0.7769) whereas when running code 2, I get for the same item: class 1 (0.9513), class 2 (0.4307), class 3 (0.7870), class 4 (0.5731). Why would the order matter?

SAS Code 1.

````
/*here is a normal order of items*/ 
items   item1 item2 item3 ... item23; /*from item1 through item23*/  

categories  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ;
RHO PRIOR=1;
seed 123741;
run;```


CODE 2 - exactly same code with exactly same items but in a different order in the item statement:

proc lca data = lca OUTPARAM = testapp outpost = lcapp_post;
nclass 4;
id qid;
/*here is another order of SAME items listed in code#1*/ 
items item3 item21 item20 item22 item19 item10.../*and the rest*/ ; 

categories  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ;
RHO PRIOR=1;
seed 123741;
run;
````